# SSAS MDX get the number of items that move from one dimensionmember to anther

Tags: ssas, mdx, transition

We've implemented a life-time-cycle for items. For this we have an Item dimension, an Phase dimension, a Date dimension and a fact table that assigns an item to a phase per date resulting in a [#Items] measure. So far so good, I can now see how many items exists in a phase over time. The question now is:

1) I would like to how many items that are in a specific phase this month, were in another phase last month. (for example, items move from an introduction phase to a mature phase, or they were already mature)

2) The other way around, how many items were in a specific phase last month but not anymore this month (for example, items move from mature last month to phase-out this month)

I'm really stuck how to get started with MDX here, any idea's how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you any knowledge in MDX? Otherwise you can look at these resources:

http://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/csi/esp/Cursos/cursos_act/2005/DAP_SistDW/Material/2-SDW-Laboratorio1-2005.pdf

http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html

If you want some help with a particular query, pls show some code and/or some diagram of tables/columns so we can help.